# MVC 5 - Handling Cancelled Requests for SQL Server .NET Client

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app in Azure that connects to Azure SQL Server using Access Tokens. I am trying to handle cases where a user navigates so quickly that requests to SQL do not seem to be completing before the user navigates elsewhere. I turned on `MultipleActiveResultSets` and started changing certain commands from Asynchronous to Synchronous. I also added try/catch blocks to every command execution to reconnect to the database, as an automatic re-connection cannot occur with an expired Access Token. The `SqlConnection` is a static object initialized when the application starts. I am having issues with `DataReader` objects still being open when the current request is cancelled and a new one is made. I had an idea to make static `DataReader` objects and check if they are open any time a new request is made but that won't work if two users make the same request simultaneously.

I think I am going about this the wrong way. This probably won't work if two users make a request at the same time. I was thinking of making a separate connection for each session but am not sure if that is the right way of going about it. A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think MultipleActiveResultSets (MARS) solves a problem here and only adds unneeded complexity. I completely agree with @usr that a static SQL connection is bad.

Comment: I had thought maybe allocating an SqlConnection per-session would be a better idea. I would really like to avoid having an SqlConnection for each request, as I would have to acquire an Access Token for each connection and that takes a little under one second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The SqlConnection is a static object initialized when the application starts.

Web applications can receive many requests from different users concurrently. Normally, it is best (and easy) to deal with this by making each request operate entirely independently of the other ones.

This means that you cannot share mutable objects such as the SQL connection. You can share mutable objects if you take great care to make it safe. It's almost never necessary and hard to get right.

Open a new connection for each HTTP request and destroy the connection at the end. Connection pooling makes this efficient. This is how it is usually done.

This is a very basic rule of web development. Maybe you should do some research on best practices for web applications. Audit your code for other shared state such as `static` variables. Likely, that code is broken.

Comment: I was hoping to improve performance by having a single connection for each instance. It takes time to acquire the Access Token, as it's in itself an HTTP request to obtain one. Maybe a connection per-session?

Comment: I don't know how it's supposed to work but you're *definitely* not supposed to maintain `SqlConnection` objects across requests. No framework would ever be designed that way. Is the access token a string? You can store that across requests in the session (but not in a static variable).

Comment: It is a string, but it expires. It takes a little under a second to obtain a new one which I'd really like to avoid having to do for every request. I need to study how IIS functions a bit more. I can't imagine IIS using the same thread for each session. Not that I think it's a very good idea to rely on IIS to prevent race conditions. You can cache variables in the application state in MVC 5 but that is no different from static objects because static objects also persist across the instance. Whatever solution I choose it can't involve re-establishing a connection for each request, which sucks.

Comment: but yes, maintaining one connection per session is an acceptable solution. As much as I'd like to avoid the overhead in acquiring the Managed Service Identity access token it sounds like maintaining a static object for the connection is a bad idea...

Comment: I moved the object that manages Azure SQL to the session object, so it's no longer static. Looks like it's working better. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Like you should make a new connection for each request but reuse the access token. The session seems the right scope to store it. If you store the connection in the session you'll have resource exhaustion problems and the connection can break. Very bad practice. It can't be designed that way.